# allow temporary url and my www too

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm facing a problem with my temporary url ip/~website and my www.website.com

My htaccess allows only my www.website.com not my ip connection. My ip/~website gives me this:

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

any ideas how to allow my temporary url and my www together?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /index.php?pagina=$1

AddCharset UTF-8 .htm
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
AddCharset UTF-8 .php

Options -MultiViews

options -indexes
```

Comment: It looks like what it did if you used the IP is attempt to redirect you to `www.255.255.255.255` which then threw a DNS resolution error. Does that seem right, given what you can see in the browser?

Comment: And do you need the temporary URL (IP) to be rewritten into `/index.php`, or not?

Comment: thank you for your answers! not possible to find DNS - ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. No, in fact I'll use the ip in my app, it will not open the index only request some .php pages from mobile folder. @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Before the existing `RewriteCond`, add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !ip.ad.dr.ess` and replace `ip.ad.dr.ess` with the real address.... That may be sufficient.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll try it! @MichaelBerkowski